# Java convert ArrayList<object> to List<String>

Tags: java, arraylist

I have a `ArrayList<Item>` as below

```
        ArrayList<Item> items = new ArrayList<Item>();
        items.add(new SectionItem("Category 1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 1", "This is item 1.1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 2", "This is item 1.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 3", "This is item 1.3"));


        items.add(new SectionItem("Category 2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 4", "This is item 2.1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 5", "This is item 2.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 6", "This is item 2.3"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 7", "This is item 2.4"));

        items.add(new SectionItem("Category 3"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 8", "This is item 3.1"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 9", "This is item 3.2"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 10", "This is item 3.3"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 11", "This is item 3.4"));
        items.add(new EntryItem("Item 12", "This is item 3.5"));
```

I want to convert it into `List<String>`. How can I do that?  I did as below but it is not working.

```
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Object Item : items) {
            result.add(Item != null ? Item.toString() : null);
        }
```

Below is my sectionItem and EntryItem

```
public class SectionItem implements Item{

    private final String title;

    public SectionItem(String title) {
        this.title = title;
    }

    public String getTitle(){
        return title;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        return true;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.toString();
    }

}

public class EntryItem implements Item{

    public final String title;
    public final String subtitle;

    public EntryItem(String title, String subtitle) {
        this.title = title;
        this.subtitle = subtitle;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isSection() {
        return false;
    }
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        return super.toString();
    }

}
```

Comment: What "is not working"? Have you overridden `toString` in both `SectionItem` and `EntryItem`?

Comment: It would be helpful to know what, if any, exceptions are thrown and what the contents of `List<String> result` is after the code has run. It would also be helpful to have the definitions of `Item`, `EntryItem`, and SectionItem.

Comment: @Mena yes i overide toString() in both ..Edited my question with details. The list is appearing with memory address instead of actual string.

Comment: @Tiz Updated my question

Comment: @Mena thank you now it is working after overiding toSting() iam not returning title. now statement return title; in toString() works.

Comment: @Mena Just returning `super.toString()` is essentially the same as not overriding it. Sounds like you've got it now though :) Good luck!

Answer (score -1):

Here is an example with strings.

```
    ArrayList<String> items = new ArrayList<String>();
    items.add("Category 1");
    items.add("This is item 1.1");
    items.add("This is item 1.2");
    items.add("This is item 1.3");
```

If you want to allocate new memory, and create copy of arraylist.

```
    List<String> itemsList2 = new ArrayList<String>(items);
    for(String item:itemsList2)
        System.out.println(item);
```

If you just want to map it to list, and reuse same arraylist object.

```
    List<String> itemsList= items;
    for(String item:itemsList)
        System.out.println(item);
```

Answer (score -2):

You should use `if` instead of trying to add `null` to the list:

```
List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (Object Item : items) {
            if(Item != null)
                result.add(Item.toString());
```